# Can't use a "for" loop in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I was having an error in which I couldn't cast an incoming variable to `int`. Changed it to `Integer`, and voilá: it's now working. I tried making a `for` loop with that variable (just testing purposes, you know), and it began throwing hundreds of errors, some of them `NullPointerException`.

Check the code:

```
<%

    Integer number = (Integer)request.getAttribute("num");
    System.out.println(number);

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){  
    System.out.println(i);
    }

%>
```

In the very beginning, I was trying to replicate some `<p>`'s so I could see this works (I pass the variable from this same view to the controller, and retrieve it back to here). If I comment the for, the correct results appear in the `System.out.println`.

This doesn't work either if I put a static value (like 5 or so) in the conditional operator of the `for` loop.

Why can't I use a for in my `view.jsp`? Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I think it should be `out.println(i);` and not `System.out.println(i);` because you want to print in your jsp page and not in the console.

Comment: "it began throwing hundreds of errors"... would you care to describe these errors please? Also, NullpointerExceptions have a location/stacktrace that should clearly point to the one `null` value being dereferenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only place where you can get `null` objects in the code that you post is in the line

```
Integer number = (Integer)request.getAttribute("num");
```

If your request doesn't have this attribute set, you should either do nothing, e.g. wrap the rest of your code in an `if(number == null) { ... }` block or initialize it explicitly, e.g. `if(number == null) number = 0;`

However, it would be most elegant to not have any scripting blocks in your JSP - rather use taglibs and EL - but that wouldn't answer your exact question, just guide you towards better (maintainable) code.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

The problem here is that you are using `System.out.println()`.

**Explanation:**

If you want to print results in the JSP page, you should use :

```
out.println(i);
```

Because if you write `System.out.println(i);` the results will be printed to the console.

Comment: correct - `System.out.println()` prints to the console, but printing to some other output stream doesn't fix a NullpointerException...

Comment: @OlafKock I am not talking about the `NullPointerException`, he said that even when he comments his code and use a static number for example `5` in the for loop it's not working.

Comment: Hm. The more I read the question, the less sense it makes. Feels like many different issues mixed into one.

Comment: Yes indeed, it is.